# Blue region in satellite image

Tags: artificial-satellite, image-processing

In one BBC article called "Etna escape: 'Pelted with the deadly, hot debris'", there was an image with the following description:

[image: Europe's Sentinel-2a satellite pictured Thursday's lava flow from space]

Europe's Sentinel-2a satellite pictured Thursday's lava flow from space

Can somebody explain the blue region of the picture? 
It could be a blend of thermal and visible satellite map?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this article](https://baltic.ai/etna-erupts/),

> The red hot lava flowing from Mount Etna can be seen clearly in the image from Sentinel-2A. The surrounding snow has been processed in blue to distinguish from the clouds.

The Sentinel satellites use [multispectral imagers](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Observing_the_Earth/Copernicus/Sentinel-2/Instrument):

> 13 spectral channels incorporating four visible and near-infrared bands at 10 m resolution, six red-edge/shortwave-infrared bands at 20 m and three atmospheric correction bands at 60 m.

So it's not so much a blend of visible and infrared channels, but a visible-light image with a false-color overlay based the composition of the soil (obtained by taking spectrograms).